# Ротация логов apache в контейнере docker без перезапуска

Tags: docker, apache2, логирование

Каталог с логами мантируется в контейнер. Ротация выполняется на хостовой системе средствами logrotate, но после ротации требуется перезапуск apache. Возможно ли выполнять ротацию без необходимости перезапускать apache, т.к. при перезапуске контейнер пересоздается, а старый падает с ошибкой.

Comment: Настройте логирование апача не в файл, а например, в pipe, и не придется тогда перезапускать его.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

зачем же перезапускать (`restart`), если достаточно перезагрузить (`reload`)? главный процесс при этом продолжит работу:

```
$ docker exec контейнер /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

именно `reload` и выполняется, например, в *debian*-овском (и, естественно, у всех наследников) конфигурационном фале `/etc/logrotate.d/apache2` из пакета *apache2*.

(предварительно уточните имя старт-стопового скрипта внутри вашего контейнера. он может называться и `/etc/init.d/apache` и `/etc/init.d/httpd` и, возможно, ещё как-нибудь в том же духе).

---

но **правильный** («docker-ский») путь, конечно, состоит в перезапуске контейнера:

```
$ docker restart контейнер
```

---

аналогичный вопрос на en.so: [How to restart apache2 without crashing docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37523338/4827341)

Comment: Контейнеров слишком много, что бы их перезапускать, в этом сложность. Да и в кластере они, т.е. дублируются на нескольких нодах, а это значит, что на всех нодах нужно делать, что уже очень трудоемко.

Answer (score 0):

В соответствии с [документацией](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/logs.html#piped) строчка конфигурации (для Apache 2.2, Red Hat 6.x, CentOS 6.x, Oracle Linux 6.x) может выглядеть так:

```
CustomLog "|$/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /var/log/httpd/access-pipeв.log 86400" combined
```

Для `ubuntu` путь к rotatelogs может быть таким: `/usr/bin/rotatelogs`

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил релоадом сервисов в самих контейнерах, в logratate в блоке prerotate добавил:
for reload in $(docker ps -q --filter name=apache); do docker exec $reload /etc/init.d/apache2 reload; done;